# Problem with materialize and loading second select using ajax

Tags: materialize

The code at https://lovelymatrimonial.com/testajax.php works perfectly fine. I select india, it outputs the list of states in second select element. I am also echoing sql just for testing.

If I try to use materialize css, the functionality fails.

I read at many places that i have to re initialize. But not good in jquery/javascript.

Please help

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script>
function showStateList(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("statesHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  } else {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("statesHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getstatelist.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
  }
  

  
}
     
</script>

</head>
<body>

                                       <div class="input-field col s3">
                                            <select name="country_id" onchange="showStateList(this.value)">
                                                <option value="0">Select Country</option>
                                                <option value="104">India - IN</option>
                                          <?php
$country_sql = "SELECT id,name,code FROM country where status='1'";
$get_country_details = mysqli_query($conn, $country_sql); // echo "aaaa" . $country_sql;
while($country = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_country_details))
    {
if ($country['id']==$country_id){$selectedd='selected';}else {$selectedd='';}
    echo    "<option value='".$country['id']."' ".$selectedd.">".$country['name']. "-" .$country['code']."</option>";
   }
?>
                                                        
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
  
                
                                                     <div  id="statesHint">
                                        </div>
  
</body> 
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/materialize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for now by adding the class browser-default to second element (select)

```
<select class='browser-default'>
```